# Proving subsets with the pythagorean identity

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have a question that defines a few sets, then asks to prove that T is a subset of C, using the Pythagorean identity. The problem is as follows:

$P = \left \{  {\frac{a}{c} \;|\; a,c\in \mathbb{N} \; and\;  a^2+b^2=c^2 \;for\;some\; b\in \mathbb{N}}\right \}$

$S = \left \{ x\in \mathbb{R} \; |\;  sin(x)\in \mathbb{Q}\right \}$

$T = \left \{ x\in \mathbb{R} \; |\;  sin(x)\in P\right \}$

$C = \left \{ x\in \mathbb{R} \; |\;  cos(x)\in \mathbb{Q}\right \}$

Prove that $T\subseteq C$

So far I have determined that:

$cos(x) = \frac{b}{c}$

$sin(x) = \frac{a}{c}$

$\left ( \frac{a}{c} \right )^2+\left ( \frac{b}{c} \right )^2 = 1$ so

$a^{2}+b^2=c^2$

Which is pretty obvious but I'm still stuck on how to prove this subset. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically on the right track with what you've done so far to prove $T\subseteq C$. Choose any $x \in T$. This means

$$\sin(x) = \frac{a}{c} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

for some $a,c \in N$ such that for some $b \in N$ you have

$$a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \implies c^2 - a^2 = b^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

You also have from $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$, plus from \eqref{eq1A} and \eqref{eq2A}, that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\cos(x) & = \pm\sqrt{1 - \sin^2(x)} \\
& = \pm\sqrt{1 - \frac{a^2}{c^2}} \\
& = \pm\sqrt{\frac{c^2 - a^2}{c^2}} \\
& = \pm\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{c^2}} \\
& = \pm\left(\frac{b}{c}\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since $b$ and $c$ are integers, this means $\cos(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$ and, thus, $x \in C$. Since $x$ was any element of $T$, this shows all elements of $T$ are in $C$ and, thus, $T$ is a subset of $C$, i.e.,

$$T\subseteq C \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

as was asked to be proven.